# .Htaccess - redirect subdomain to root domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am aware this subject has come up a few times in conversation on SO, however I do believe my issue is quite bespoke and as an unexperienced apache htaccess coder I am unsure as to where to look or what to properly ask.

**My target:**

my domain `(www.mydomain.com)`

My target `(www.shop.mydomain.com)`

When a user directs to `'my domain'`, the server points to the `'shop`' subfolder BUT this doesn't change the domain visible in the URL.

**My problem:**

I have achieved this 'partially' however when I navigate to another page for example: `/about` within the `/shop` folder, I will receive a 404 error because the server is looking in `mydomain.com/about` rather than `mydomain.com/shop/about`.

From what it looks like, the server is looking at the `'shop'` for the root and in the actually root directory for the rest of the website.

I would like the entire website to be run from the `/shop` folder but the domain to stay as `mydomain.com/about` etc.

I am lost, and cannot achieve this. My current apache rewrite is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shop/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ shop/index.php [L]
```

Any advice and help? :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ shop/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (?!^shop/)^(.+)$ /shop/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: This actually works nicely. Thank you! I'm lost on apache rewrites!